# Wordpress form submit to custom page template does not work

Tags: pages, templates, urls, forms, page-template

I have a form on the home page, which when user submits, the action takes him to another page. That another page is using my custom made page template `page-quiz.php`. So for the form submit action I'm using this file. Unfortunately, when I submit the form, I get page not found.

The actual page is created inside admin dashboard. It seems like the template file name and page url is different. I tried making the url the same as the name of the temlate file `page-quiz.php` but I get the same page not found problem.

My index.php form code:

```
...<div class="forma">
    <h2 style="text-align: center; color: #E45E5D; font-weight: 700;">Register for quiz</h2>
        <form action="page-quiz.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="asd" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter full name" name="kasd" required>


</div> ....
```

page-quiz.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 * Template Name: Quiz
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package okindk
 */
/*wp_head()*/
get_header('header-quiz'); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

      <div id="container" class="container container_quiz">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="questions" class="lead">
            <p></p>
            </div>

            <p id="options" class="center-block">


            </p>
              <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
          </div>


           <?php echo $_SESSION\["email"\]; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

How can I get around this?

[image]

Comment: In WordPress this does not look right: ``<form action="page-quiz.php" method="post">`` | You have to do something like ``get_template_directory_uri()`` to get to the file path or you can link to http://mysite(dot)com/quiz

Comment: Exactly - you need to use the page permalink rather than a link to your template file. You'll also want to add a conditional, above `get_header()` - to check for `$_POST['asd']` and `$_POST['kasd']` - if either are empty, show the form so the visitor must enter your required information; if they are both set, show the quiz.

Comment: Can you guys explain how to use `get_template_directory_uri()` in my case, because I can't make it work when using inside Action